# storybook with ant design theme less not working

Tags: webpack, less, antd, storybook

I am trying to set up storybook with Ant Design, and a custom Ant Design theme.
The theme uses a less css file to override the theme properties.

However, when I try to complie storybook I get the following error:

```
// https://github.com/ant-design/ant-motion/issues/44
.bezierEasingMixin();
^
Inline JavaScript is not enabled. Is it set in your options?
```

I have configured less to enable inline javascript in my storybook main.js file as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../stories/**/*.stories.tsx'],

  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-docs',
    '@storybook/addon-actions', 
    '@storybook/addon-essentials', 
    '@storybook/addon-backgrounds'],
  
    webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
      config.module.rules.push({
        // this is for both less and scss
        test: /.*\.(?:le|c|sc)ss$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'style-loader'
        }, {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: false
          }
        }, {
          loader: 'less-loader',
          options: {
              javascriptEnabled: true
          }
        }, {
          loader: 'sass-loader'
        }
      ]
      });
      config.plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name]-[contenthash].css',
        chunkFilename: '[id]-[contenthash].css',
      }));
      return config;
    },
};
```

As you can see in the snippet above, the less loader has the javascriptEnabled option set to true.

Any suggestions to get this to work will be greatly appreciated. TIA!

**EDIT Add current config:**

```
[
  {
    test: /\.(mjs|tsx?|jsx?)$/,
    use: [ [Object] ],
    include: [ '/Users/...' ],
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    use: [ [Object] ],
    include: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](@storybook\/node-logger|are-you-es5|better-opn|boxen|chalk|commander|find-cache-dir|find-up|fs-extra|json5|node-fetch|pkg-dir|resolve-from|semver)/
  },
  { test: /\.md$/, use: [ [Object] ] },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: /node_modules\/acorn-jsx/,
    use: [ [Object] ]
  },
  { test: /\.(stories|story).mdx$/, use: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  {
    test: /\.mdx$/,
    exclude: /\.(stories|story).mdx$/,
    use: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.(stories|story)\.[tj]sx?$/,
    loader: '/Users/.../Storybook/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/index.js',
    options: { injectStoryParameters: true, inspectLocalDependencies: true },
    enforce: 'pre'
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    sideEffects: true,
    use: [
      '/Users/.../Storybook/node_modules/@storybook/core/node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js',
      [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.(svg|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani|pdf)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: '/Users/.../Storybook/node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js',
    options: { name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]', esModule: false }
  },
  {
    test: /\.(mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: '/Users/.../Storybook/node_modules/url-loader/dist/cjs.js',
    query: { limit: 10000, name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]' }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is from you apply the rule for your import without options like this:

```js
import '!style-loader!css-loader!less-loader!../css/theme.less';
```

Since you already declared the rules for your `.less` file which means you just simply import it normally like this:

```js
import '../css/theme.less';
```

One more thing, you have to refine is to split `less` and `scss` files as separate rules instead of combining them together which is likely ending up an issue. Plus, `MiniCssExtractPlugin` is also unnecessary here since `style-loader` is being used to append style on document.

In short, here are the few things you would change. Please also read my inline comment as well:

`preview.js`

```js
import '../css/theme.less';
// In case of being keen for `scss` file
import '../css/layout.scss';

export const parameters = {
  // ...
}
```

`main.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../stories/**/*.stories.tsx'],

  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-docs',
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-backgrounds'
  ],

  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      // this is for both less and scss
      test: /.*\.(?:le|c)ss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: false
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'less-loader',
          options: {
            lessOptions: {
              javascriptEnabled: true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    
    // If you wish to use `scss` file
    // Keep in mind to install `sass` which I don't see it as apart of your deps
    // npm i -D sass
    config.module.rules.push({
      // this is for both less and scss
      test: /.*\.(?:sc|c)ss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: false
          }
        },
        'sass-loader',
      ]
    });

    // I don't think you need this anymore since `style-loader` is being used 
    // config.plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    //   filename: '[name]-[contenthash].css',
    //   chunkFilename: '[id]-[contenthash].css',
    // }));

    return config;
  },
};
```

That's it! Hope it would help you more about `webpack` + `storybook` working together.

Comment: thanks @tmhao2005, yes I tried the lessOptions as well, but same error. Thanks for your suggestion, but where exactly to I check the current config argument of webpackFinal?

Comment: You can check by `console.log(config.module)` right before you push your custom rule.

Comment: thanks, I did that, there is no loader handling for .less. I have edited my original question with the output of the console log. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hmmm. Do you have a reproducible repo?

Comment: will set one up, will take a little while though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224776/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-ronny-vdb).

Comment: sent you the link to the repo in chat

Comment: Thank you so much! you are a life saver

Comment: @Ronnyvdb, I got the same problem and tried to fix it with your solution. But I got a new error:

ERROR in ./projects/src/ng-zorro-theme.less
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):

var api = require("!../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js");
      ^
Unrecognised input

Is there anything I missed from your solution?

Comment: @xingkong did you resolved your issue? I have the same problem

Comment: @Ronnyvdb how did the solution look in the end? I tried attached answer but keep getting errors (as mentioned above).

Comment: I also have same problem as @xingkong.